# Use function to change PHP variable name

Tags: php

kindly need your help,

I'm trying to use function to change the name of a PHP variable. I tried to change $name to $graph1, $graph2 ... $graph31. Here's the code I made:

```
<?php
function bar($name, $label, $value) {
    return
$name = new BAR_GRAPH("pBar");
$name->values = $value;
$name->labels = $label;
$name->labelColor = "white";
$name->labelBGColor  = "#282828";
$name->barBorder = "0px";
$name->barColors    = "white";
$name->barBGColor  = "#282828";
$name->showValues   = 0;
$name->percValuesColor    = "white";
$name->barColors    = "white";
echo $name->create();
}


bar("$graph1","ornamen","$totkakiOrnamen;7");

?>
```

Unfortunately the code doesn't work, it says:

> Notice: Undefined variable: graph in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\process.php
>   on line 56

I don't know what's wrong. How can I change $name to $graph1, $graph2 ... $graph31 ?

PS: The return code looks weird because I used gerd-tentler's script to generate horizontal bar. http://www.gerd-tentler.de/tools/phpgraphs/?page=introduction

Comment: What do you ever mean by change the name of a variable?

Comment: This may or may not be what you are asking: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Hi @joey i want to change $name to $graph1, $graph2 etc.

Comment: You mean you want to pass different variables, $graph1, $graph2 to the function bar - right? Looking at the code above the "return" statement has been used in a wrong manner. Paste all your code (esp line 56) and maybe we can help.

Comment: Hi @Rasclatt that might be my answer! I'll try to include it on my code! Thanks!

Comment: Hi @JoeyEzekiel line 56 refers to bar("'$graph'","ornamen","$totkakiOrnamen;7");

Comment: Ok, have you tried what Rasclatt has given you? Is that what you need? You may want to add the $graph1->create(); at the end of his code if I think what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Hey @Rasclatt , the code works! Thanks for your suggestion man!

Comment: I'm not even sure what this code does, so I uncommented that out but didn't echo it.

Comment: Ok great! I'm glad I made it sound like I knew what the heck I was doing....??

Comment: @Rasclatt Hahaha but your link is really the thing I searched for :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be what you are asking but maybe....??

```
<?php
    function bar($name, $label, $value) {
            $$name                  =   new BAR_GRAPH("pBar");
            $$name->values          =   $value;
            $$name->labels          =   $label;
            $$name->labelColor      =   "white";
            $$name->labelBGColor    =   "#282828";
            $$name->barBorder       =   "0px";
            $$name->barColors       =   "white";
            $$name->barBGColor      =   "#282828";
            $$name->showValues      =   0;
            $$name->percValuesColor =   "white";
            $$name->barColors       =   "white";
            $$name->create();
            return $$name;
        }

    $graph1 = bar('graph1',"ornamen","$totkakiOrnamen;7"); ?>
```

if not, the only other guess is that you are trying to do a variable variable:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Hi, I solved it by writing $$name instead of $name and "graph1" instead of "$graph1", thanks!

Comment: So was it the function revision or the variable link or both?? I want to edit my answer so it's not confusing...

Comment: Both, $name should be changed to $$name, and the last line should be changed to 

bar("graph1","ornamen","$totkakiOrnamen;7"); 

notice that I deleted "$" before "graph1)